# How to retrieve user tweets

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to get the Twitter user tweets through this code:

```
 public void displayTweets() throws TwitterException{

    uri = getIntent().getData();
    System.out.println(uri);
    verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

    try {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        //List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getRetweets(userID);
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
        System.out.println("done.");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to get retweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I got nothing as display, and I got this log (with LogCat):

**Log-Cat :**

```
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552): <hash>
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552):   <error>Invalid / expired Token</error>
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552):   <request>/oauth/access_token</request>
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552): </hash>
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
06-25 12:55:43.811: W/System.err(24552):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1aec76dd or
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=80621963
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[1aec76dd-80621963], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:139)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:159)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:370)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.afficherTweets(MainActivity.java:274)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at com.androidhive.twitterconnect.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:411)
06-25 12:55:43.816: W/System.err(24552):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
06-25 12:55:43.821: W/System.err(24552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do You have Consumer key and consumer secret and have you used it ???

Comment: ello you can check this sample application it is open source and easy to understand [Android Tweeter Sample](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample)[

Comment: It appears that you're not authorized (`401`). Are your keys valid? I'm not at my computer where I've used twitter4j atm, but the auth portion looks like it may be missing something. I'll try to check back in later. In the mean time, I'd check on dev.twitter.com and use those creds to make a query (they have and option on the documentation pages that will do it for you).